# jsoup - How do I filter all elements that are contained in a div of a specific class?

Tags: jsoup

I have a div that contains lots of stuff I want to ignore.

```
<div class="product-list">
...tons of stuff many levels deep that I want to ignore
</div>
```

I tried tacking `.product-list` at the end of a list of "not" selectors, like this:

```
elements.not("sel1, sel2, sel3, .product-list");
```

Then I tried tacking `.product-list *` at the end of a list of "not" selectors thinking that meant *all children* of elements of the class ".product-list", like this:

```
elements.not("sel1, sel2, sel3, .product-list *");
```

None of this has worked. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

if you are trying to skip div class use pesudo selector like this

```
div:not(.product-list)
```

it should work

Comment: I am trying to use the elements.not() function to exclude elements with a given class, and all of those elements children too.

Comment: then why dont you choose elements you need , with multiple select statement , i think it would be easy for me to understand if you could show me actual page source and what you want to parse off that page

Comment: Because I want them all, except the ones encapsulated in divs of a specific class. And it's not for one page; it's an automated extract for our entire site. It would be far easier if I could just say "except anything contained in a div of class .product-list"

Comment: not statement should work fine for you then 
you can give multiple div classses in  one not selector if there are couple of div classes you want to skip

Comment: The problem is that, although the not statement works for the ".product-list" class elements themselves, it doesn't exclude their children, grandchildren, etc.

Comment: not function should have excluded child elements as well, anyways did you try using remove function on those divs ?
doc.select(div.product-list).remove();
it will remove whole div tag ,i think this should help